# Barcode Scanning Winform c#

Tags: barcode

I used  code39 ttf for barcode generation with * as start and end letter.  As my barcode is * 1234 * it gives me correct answer.  But by mistaken i print barcode with ** 1234 ** (double start and end letter ) and now my barcode is not recognised by scanner.  But all the prints are sticked on Products now is there any way to scan barcode which  contains  (** 1234 **) data.

Comment: This is not a programming related question, unless you will show your code.

Comment: if the scanner isnt reading it, Id pick the simple answer no.

Comment: I'd say the scanner might be reading two empty codes (as `**` is `start-nothing-end`). Is there a way you can replace the `start` and `end` detection from `*` to `**` ? If you decided `*` on the first place, then maybe yes.

Comment: @Rafalon is correct. I've reviewed the documentation on my scanner, and it lists no way of configuring the scanner to ignore the start/stop characters and pass them along. I've also tried to just cover up the first start character, but my scanner still won't read the barcode. I'm guessing that's because it doesn't detect enough white space after the first stop character or reaches the last stop character and considers the two stop characters together as syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must change your code, while reading the barcode you must remove the first and the last character(*), and then use the value in your software.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause for a barcode font failing to scan is a missing or incorrect start, stop or check digit(symbol). In this case your start and stop symbols are incorrect, and scanner cannot pick that up as valid code39 barcode. The only thing you can do now - reprint stickers.

Note : It's not programming related question btw, so you can easily remove c#/winforms tags.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can salvage a code 39 barcode like that is to cover with white paper or use white-out on the first and last characters. The characters visible in this graphic.

[image]